# How to get PoolingDataSource from Tomcat's JNDI

Tags: java, tomcat, database-connection, jndi

If I deploy a web app to Tomcat, and have code like this:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("jdbc/myDB");
```

How can I specify for this `DataSource` to be a `PoolingDataSource`? How do I configure the pool (`GenericObjectPool`) to inject the `PoolingDataSource` with?

Or, is this the default behavior of Tomcat's JNDI implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Just configure the connection pool settings (maxActive, maxWait, maxIdle, ...).
Tomcat comes with the apache commons-dbcp library. It is repackaged as  $CATALINA_HOME/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar.

Take a look at the tomcat doc for details: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Database_Connection_Pool_%28DBCP%29_Configurations

```
<Context>
  <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
               username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The **JDBC Connection Pool `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool`** 
>     is a replacement or an alternative to the [commons-dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)
>     connection pool.

1. Add to the `server.xml` file in the `GlobalNamingResources` section something like the next:

   ```
   <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" 
             auth="Container" 
             type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
             factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
             testWhileIdle="true"
             testOnBorrow="true"
             testOnReturn="false"
             validationQuery="SELECT 1"
             validationInterval="30000"
             timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
             maxActive="100" 
             minIdle="10" 
             maxWait="10000" 
             initialSize="10"
             removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
             removeAbandoned="true"
             logAbandoned="true"
             minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000" 
             jmxEnabled="true"
             jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
             username="root" 
             password="password" 
             driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
             url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"/>
   ```
2. Add the JDBC driver JAR into the Tomcat lib directory.
3. Add in your `context.xml`:

   ```
   <ResourceLink global="jdbc/TestDB" name="jdbc/TestDB" 
                 type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
   ```

See more in [*The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool*](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html).